# What kernels are safe to use in 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, kernel

I'm considering an upgrade from

```
$ uname -r
3.5.0-26-generic
```

to kernel 3.8.5.

Is this tested on 12.10, and is it safe to upgrade?

Comment: No. Only 3.5 is tested in 12.10, and 3.8 is planned for 13.04.

Comment: So you wouldn't recommend upgrading?

Comment: Depends. I don't know why you'd like to upgrade, which makes it hard to advise.

Comment: I believe I read somewhere, something like "New kernel = Best kernel"? Although this seems to not be the case?

Comment: No the best kernel is the one that works. The general consensus is: "if it aint broken ...". Unless you are faced with a problem that needs a newer kernel leave it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always a potential issue when upgrading the kernel, but unless your configuration is highly specialized or unique, upgrading is an option. FYI - both 3.8.5 and 3.9-rc5 are compatible with 12.04 and 12.10. Even 13.04 (beta) running 3.8.0-15 is quite stable. Good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend such an upgrade on a productive system, as it can cause some big troubles with the drivers. Once I've tried such an upgrade and it really messed up with my graphic drivers. and as ubuntu 13.04 is just a few weeks away it isn't worth it. you should wait for the new ubuntu and play it save.